# Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ASHISH_PC while invoking web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, jboss7.x

Hi all as I am trying to invoke web service throw web service client. created through

```
http://118.102.123.190:8080/Myproject/TestConfigWS?wsdl
```

URL but I am getting `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ASHISH_PC` error.

after investigating bit and reading **[this](http://www.adcworks.com/2008/04/php-soapclient-could-not-connect-to-host/)** article I found that I have to make a host entry to solve this problem.

```
118.102.123.190 ASHISH_PC
```

after making entry It solve the error,***but in my case it's not a best way to make an entry of each and every host in my hosts file*** 
so I want an alternative way to solve this problem can some one help me on this ?

*Web Service Implementer Class*

```
@javax.jws.WebService(
                      serviceName = "TestConfigWSService",
                      portName = "TestConfigWSPort",
                      targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/",
                      wsdlLocation = "http://118.102.123.190:8080/Myproject/TestConfigWS?wsdl",
                      endpointInterface = "com.mypackage.TestConfigWS")

public class TestConfigWSImpl implements TestConfigWS {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mypackage.TestConfigWS#test(java.lang.String  arg0 )*
     */
    public boolean test(java.lang.String arg0) { 
        LOG.info("Executing operation test");
        System.out.println(arg0);
        try {
            boolean _return = false;
            return _return;
        } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }   

}
```

*TestConfigWSService.wsdl*

```
<wsdl:service name="TestConfigWSService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:TestConfigWSServiceSoapBinding" name="TestConfigWSPort">
<soap:address location="http://ASHISH_PC:8080/Myproject/TestConfigWS"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In short how can I replace **ASHISH_PC** with my **IP** (i.e. 118.102.123.190) in my

```
<soap:address location="http://ASHISH_PC:8080/Myproject/TestConfigWS"/>
```

attribute Thanks...

**Web- Server**

I am using JBOSS AS 7 to deploy my web service.

jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution I have added `jbossws.undefined.host` value in `<wsdl-host>` attribute in `standalone.xml` file under `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration` location as follows

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
```

this solves my problem It replace `ASHISH_PC` with my IP in my `<soap:address>` attribute.